# FFmpeg move overlay from one pixel coordinate to another

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to write a command within FFmpeg that will first overlay one video stream on top of another one.  Then I want the overlayed video to move from one pixel coordinate at a known time, and end at another pixel coordinate at a later time.

I'm comfortable with the basics of the `-filter_complex`, but I cannot figure out how to apply any arithmetic expressions - like the one's referenced here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation

Here's an example of something I'd like to accomplish.

```
ffmpeg -i [INPUT1] -i [INPUT2] -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1:x=720:y=0:enable='between(t,10,20)'[overlay];...
```

In this example the overlay is stationary at pixel coordinate 720x0 from the 10th second to the 20th second.

However, Id like to have it move to a new location in a linear fashion and end at a different pixel coordinate.

For example, during that 10 second overlay, I'd like to have it start at 720x0, but then end at 1000x100.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this about what you're looking for?

[image: making a movement]

This crappy example has a duration of 6 seconds. The red box appears after 2 seconds and ends 3 seconds later.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i bg.mp4 -i fg.mkv -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,10,20)':x=720+t*28:y=t*10[out]" \
-map "[out]" output.mkv
```

- Move `x` from position 720 to 1000 in 10 seconds. That equals 28 pixels/second.
- `y` is easy enough.
- `t` is the timestamp in seconds.
- The overlaid video (`fg.mkv` in this example) will already be 10 seconds into its duration when it appears.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I was originally struggling to understand what the `t*28` area meant - but that makes perfect sense that it is a pixel value changing at a rate of 28 pixels per second.  Could this work in a scale filter like: `scale=720+t*2:480`?  I would expect that would increase the X pixel value by 2 every second.  Is that correct?

Comment: Hey, how would this work if we wanted to use this with a fade in and fade out for the moving element as well?

Comment: @NavedKhan Probably. See the [fade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) filter. There are several usages examples on SO.