# FFMpeg - move overlay from point a to b to c to d

Tags: ffmpeg

I used somebody else's code posted by LordNeckbeard here: [FFmpeg move overlay from one pixel coordinate to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384577/ffmpeg-move-overlay-from-one-pixel-coordinate-to-another)

I modified it a bit to this:

```
    ffmpeg -i 4632.mpg -i 4632.bmp -filter_complex "[0]scale=320:240[over];
    [1][over]overlay=enable='between=(t,0,50)':x=20+t*30:y=20+t*20" -s 
    1280:720 -c:a copy -y output.mpg
```

I'd like to be able to limit the movement so the overlay does not go off screen.
How can I move a scaled clip overlay in four directions, X & Y starting from originating location and back?

Answer (score 4):

This step-wise motion has to be constructed using a union of conditional expressions. Basic syntax of each unit is

`(origin + (destination - origin)*(t - start time)/duration) * between(t,start time,end time)`

Then all units are added together, like in the example below.

Let's say you want to move the clip from `(ax,ay)` to `(bx,by)` to `(cx,cy)` and back to `(ax,ay)`. Let's keep each leg to 10 seconds.

Syntax is `overlay=x='(ax+(bx-ax)*(t-0)/10)*between(t,0,10)+(bx+(cx-bx)*(t-10)/10)*between(t,10,20)+(cx+(ax-cx)*(t-20)/10)*between(t,20,30)':y='(ay+(by-ay)*(t-0)/10)*between(t,0,10)+(by+(cy-by)*(t-10)/10)*between(t,10,20)+(cy+(ay-cy)*(t-20)/10)*between(t,20,30)'`

Comment: How can I smooth out the movement? I'm looking at a similar effect done on adobe premiere and the animation moves smoothly compared to ffmpeg result.

Comment: Share the Premiere video.

Comment: I uploaded it on youtube but I have to make it private since it's work related. What email can I share it with or how can I share it to you only?

Comment: BTW - I tried this example you gave on another post but I have to add it in the -filter_complex statement at the very end: [out]minterpolate=60,tblend=all_mode=average,framestep=2 but didn't see a difference

Comment: "This video is unavailable"

Comment: I need an email to share a private video. Unfortunately, I can't make it public.

Comment: Please let me know if you got the notification.